# Logging ModelState errors in base controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to log all ModelState errors in a base controller for reference. I thought about overriding OnActionExecuting, but I'm not sure whether this is the right place to have that logging done. My idea is to have the actions free from that logging code. Is this override the correct place or is there a better place?

Comment: I would use the `OnActionExecuted` method because if your actions adding custom errors to the ModelState then they would be also logged... or put the logic into a ActionFilter and not the base class so you can be apply it more flexible. But generally there is no one real good place for this it is all depending on your actual needs.

Comment: @nemesv Post your comment as an answer as you were first to propose the attribute solution I would accept that answer

Comment: You should accept @Slicksim answer, instead of me creating a new answer which adds no additional value and only just for you to accept it.

Comment: @nemesv ok. thought it would be fair enough to provide you with the chance to get the respect in terms of the chosen solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you thought about doing this as an attribute instead.

Rather than overriding each the onactionexecuting of a base controller, you can decorate the actions that you are interested in and have the attribute override the onactionexecuting there and do the logging that you require.

You might find that a better fit than blanketing the whole controller.